# Add/Remove column in trirand jqgrid (dynamically)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am using trirand jQGrid with .net mvc 4. I need to decide which columns to dislplay when I fetch the data from database(in database I have stored which columns to display). Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to hide the columns which you don't want to show.

var strColumns = 'a,b,c';
$("#myGrid").hideCol(strColumns);

Comment: Actually i want to fetch data only for columns that are required to be displayed.So want to dynamically add columns to grid ...if possible.thanks.